# Lost years worth of passwords & bookmarks on my Chrome desktop, but still on my iPhone

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, passwords, sync, iphone

I don't know what I did but I lost years worth of saved passwords and bookmarks on my desktop.  They are still on my iphone but I'm so afraid of "syncing" and losing them permanently.  I checked the applications folder on my laptop and there is no backup there.  I also do not have a restore set up on my desktop.  Honestly, I don't know if that would have worked anyway.

Fortunately, the passwords and bookmarks are saved on my iphone device.  Is there a way to backup my saved passwords and bookmarks on my iphone device just in case syncing doesn't work?  I am paranoid that if I set my iphone to sync to all devices that I might lose all my passwords and bookmarks on my iphone and then I'm really screwed!

Currently I have sync turned off on my devices.  I did this just in case syncing my desktop with my iphone may erase everything on my iphone.  I want to sync where I can restore everything on my iphone back onto my desktop.  Right now my desktop doesn't have any saved passwords and the only bookmarks my desktop has are what is on the desktop (laptop) device).

Should I restart the sync from my iphone or from my desktop.  Is the desktop sync the "default" -- that is what I'm afraid of.  That is the syncing defaults to desktop then I might lose all the info on my iphone as well.  I'm not even sure if this is how syncing works.

Please help.  It used to sync perfectly.  I'm not sure what I did, but one day I just noticed that my "mobile" bookmarks on my desktop were gone and so were the passwords.  Fortunately, past bookmarks and passwords are still on my iphone device.  How do I fix this issue so that I can sync seamlessly again.   I rely too much on google, gmail and chrome.

I hope I am making sense.  I am not very eloquent when it comes to explaining techie stuff.  Sorry!

Comment: Synchronisation has always been a little bit difficult to decipher. I don't know of any way to tell whether the Desktop will be considered the "source" or most up to date system to sync across devices - thus wiping all the others. One possible solution would be to uninstall chrome on your desktop and reinstall it, then activate sync *just on your desktop*. It should then synchronise with your google account with no risk of deleting anything. If all your passwords re-appear all is well. If not, it looks like something has gone wrong and we would have to look at other solutions.

Comment: That sounds like an answer –– why not post it as such?

Comment: Only because I have guessed a solution here and can't back it up with any references or testing. But would you recommend converting it to an answer?

Comment: You can also use *keychain* to export passwords: https://www.cnet.com/how-to/how-to-retrieve-icloud-keychain-passwords-on-ios/

Comment: What do you currently have in https://chrome.google.com/sync and in https://passwords.google.com ?